# animate div after scrolling to container

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrollto

I created a #nav div that i'd like to animate with jquery and slide it to the section with the class .active after the scrollto function is complete.
The .active class is appended to the section that was clicked.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to get the distance between the browser-window and the active section and animate the #nav div to slide it there.

Update: I can't use position-fixed as:

- the #nav will be part of a responsive css grid.
- if the last section is short the #nav div won't scroll further down
  than the browser windows allows.

My js:

```
$("a").click(function () {

    //remove class  from href
    $(".active").removeClass("active");

    //add class to href
    var highlight_href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(highlight_href).addClass("active");


    $('html, body').scrollTo($('.active'), 300, {
        onAfter: function () {
            $("#nav").stop().animate({
                // animate #nav and slide to the section with the .active class
            });
        }
    });

});
```

I also created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SBPEn/1/):

Answer (score 0):

Use css `position:fixed` on `#nav`:

[Here is jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/SBPEn/2/)

```
#nav {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    margin:20px;
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, i forgot to mention that i can't use position-fixed. the sections and the #nav will be part of a responsive css grid. so position: fixed would cause problems. also i'd like to use animate instead of scroll because otherwise the #nav div won't scroll to the .active section if the last section is short and there's not enough space available to scroll.